# Add -unittest argument to compiler with VisualD

Tags: visual-studio, d

I'm starting out with D using VisualD and my unit test seem to be ignored.

When I go to project properties -> configuration properties -> General, I can check "Use other compiler" and manual add -unittest to the compiler path. This does not work. So how do you compile with the argument -unittest ?

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the correct way to add the argument:

Project properties -> Configuration Properties -> Command line -> Additional options: -unittest

Answer (score 0):

The unit test runs when you run your program but if there are no failures nothing is reported.  If you want to see an example of some output write a unit test that fails.  After the unit test runs the program itself will generally run unless you some conditional stuff to make it not happen.

Comment: I wrote a unit test that fails. Nothing happens. (Unless I check the "use other compiler" option and add "-unittest" as parameter. But then I'd like to see some error message saying my unit test failed or something instead of just "build failed"...)

Comment: @user1073075 it is strange that no compiler output is shown, check the build output in the output window

Comment: Good suggestion, now I see why it fails: "C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\dmd.exe -unittest" is not recognized as an internal or external command'

Comment: My bad I misread your question and thought you had already checked the unit test box and were wondering why after checking you didn't get your test runs.